# Create more then 100 workbooks in a single Excel file.The code works fine. Is there any way to make this happen in less time like less then a minute?

Tags: php, api, google-analytics-api

This is a function I have created to create more then 100 workbooks in a Single file. Code works fine but it takes longer time to complete the entire process. I would like to know the way I could make these things faster. Thank you all for reading this post.

```
function allStats() {


    $data['total'] = $this->poster_model->numberTotalPiosters();
    $data['allPosters'] = $this->poster_model->getAllPosters(); 



    require(APPPATH.'third_party/gapi.php');
    $ga = new gapi('xxx@xxxx', 'xxxxx');

    require(APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel.php');
    require(APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("xxxxxx");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("xxxxxx");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("xxxxxxx");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("xxxxxx");
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("xxxxx (".$data['allPosters'][$i]['PDF_Name'].")");

    $i=0;

    while ($i < 150) 
    {

        if($data['allPosters'][$i]['Translations']==0)
        {

        if(time() < strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Expiry_Date'])){
            $expiry = date('Y-m-d');
            $limit = round((strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Expiry_Date']) - time()) / 86400);
        }else if(strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Expiry_Date']) == strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Presentation_Date'])){
            $expiry = strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Presentation_Date']) + 86400;
            $limit = 1;
        }else{
            $expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Expiry_Date']));
            $limit = round((strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Expiry_Date']) - strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Presentation_Date'])) / 86400);

        }

        $ga->requestReportData(
            xxxxxxxx,
            array('date','eventAction'),
            array('uniqueEvents'), 
            array('eventAction'),
            'eventAction=='.base_url().'uploads/'.$data['allPosters'][$i]['PDF_Name'], 
            date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Presentation_Date'])), 
            $expiry, 
            1,
            $limit
        );
        $download_stats = array();
        foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){
            $download_stats[$result->getDate()] = array(
                'pageviews' => $result->getUniqueEvents()
            );
        }
        $data['downloads'] = $ga->getUniqueEvents(); 
        $ga->requestReportData(
            xxxxxxx,
            array('date'),
            array('pageviews','uniquepageviews','visitors'), 
            array('date'), 
            'pagePath==/test/'.$data['allPosters'][$i]['Path'], 
            date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Presentation_Date'])), 
            $expiry, 
            1,
            $limit
        );
    $stats = array();
        foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){
        $stats[] = array(
                'origdate' => $result->getDate(),
                'date' => date('j F Y', strtotime($result->getDate())),
                'pageviews' => $result->getPageviews(),
                'uniquepageviews' => $result->getUniquePageviews(),
                'visitors' => $result->getVisitors()
            );
        }
        $data['page_views'] = number_format($ga->getPageviews());
        $data['unique_page_views'] = number_format($ga->getUniquePageviews());
        $data['visitors'] = number_format($ga->getVisitors());
        $ga->requestReportData(
            xxxxxxxx,
            array('date'),
            array('pageviews'), 
            array('date'),
            'pagePath==/test/'.$data['allPosters'][$i]['Path'].'/pdf-emailed.php', 
            date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Presentation_Date'])), 
            $expiry, 
            1,
            $limit
        );
        $email_stats = array();
        foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){
            $email_stats[] = array(
                'origdate' => $result->getDate(),
                'date' => date('j F Y', strtotime($result->getDate())),
                'pageviews' => $result->getPageviews()
            );
        }
        $data['email_views'] = number_format($ga->getPageviews());
        $data['stats'] = $stats;
        $data['email_stats'] = $email_stats;
        $data['download_stats'] = $download_stats;


        $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($data['allPosters'][$i]['Identifier']);

        $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('A1', 'Date');
        $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('B1', 'Unique page views');
        $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('C1', 'Page views');
        $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('D1', 'Visitors');
        $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('E1', 'Downloads');
        $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('F1', 'e-mails');
        $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('G1', 'SMS');

        $a = 2;
        foreach($stats as $stat){

            $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('A'.$a, $stat['date']);
            $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('B'.$a, intval($stat['uniquepageviews']));
            $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('C'.$a, intval($stat['pageviews']));
            $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('D'.$a, intval($stat['visitors']));


            $dd=$a;

        for($j=0;$j<=$total;$j++)
        {
                //$data['sms'][$j]['from_number']
                //$data['sms'][$j]['date'];
                $datetocompare=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($stat['date']));
                if((strtotime($datetocompare))==(strtotime($data['sms'][$j]['date'])) ){
                if(isset($data['sms'][$j]['numbers_of_sms'])){
                $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('G'.$a, ($data['sms'][$j]['numbers_of_sms'] ));
                }else{
                $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('G'.$a, 0);
                }
                }
        $dd++;
        }
            if(isset($download_stats[$stat['origdate']])){
                $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('E'.$a, intval($download_stats[$stat['origdate']]['pageviews']));
            }else{
                $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('E'.$a, 0);
            }
            if(isset($email_stats[$a-2])){
                $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('F'.$a, intval($email_stats[$a-2]['pageviews']));
            }else{
                $objWorkSheet->SetCellValue('F'.$a, 0);
            }

            $a++;
        }

        $objWorkSheet->setTitle($data['allPosters'][$i]['Identifier']);

    $i++;
    }

}
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save('uploads/allposters/'.md5($i).'.xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Replace your while loop over $i with this for-loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < 150; ++$i){
...Preincrement is faster on php, dont ask me why. Do this on your other for loops as well.
}
```

2.You call this function multiple times during a loop chain:

```
strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Expiry_Date'])
```

Call it only once and store the result in a variable, e.g.

```
$strt = strtotime($data['allPosters'][$i]['Expiry_Date']);
```

Then replace all occurances with the variable. Do the same with similar redundant function calls.

3.I don't know how your ga-Object works, but you have the loop:

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result){
...
}
```

two times almost directly behind each other. The first time for the array `$download_stats`, the second time for `$stats` and the third time for the array `$email_stats`.

Check if you can unite those two loops or if you can modify your code so you only have to fetch the gesults one time.

Also, call the function

```
$ga->getResults()
```

only once and store the results in a variable and iterate over the array then, e.g.

```
$results = $ga->getResults();
foreach($results as $result){
...
}
```

Try to reduce your function calls wherever possible.

So far. I hope I could help :)

Comment: Hay Dear, thank you very much for taking time and gone through the code. Surely, I will make those changes and confirm the results. Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Corsair, Thank you very much for your help. It did speed up a little bit but not hugely. I am still trying to combile those three request. Thanks for your help. Take care.. :)